# Android unique work manager returning null result on observable

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Hi i am trying to use the below code snippet to create a unique job scehdular via work manager and observe the result state but the result is outputting as null?

if i use enqueWork instead of enqueUniqueWork, it works fine.

Below is my code:

```
 val pollingWorkRequest: OneTimeWorkRequest =  OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<TestResultsWorker>()
                .addTag(TestResultsWorker.TAG)
                .build()    
workManager.enqueueUniqueWork(TestResultsWorker.TAG, ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, pollingWorkRequest)
        workManager.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(pollingWorkRequest.id)
  .observe(
                this,
                { result ->
                    when (result.state) {
                        WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED -> success(result)
                        WorkInfo.State.FAILED -> failed(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use: **getWorkInfosForUniqueWorkLiveData()**

Also, you are using **enqueueUniqueWork()** in the wrong way. There is a difference between a **TAG** and a **name**. In **enqueueUniqueWork** you must provide a **unique name** for a **single unique work**.

But at the same time, you can group **many unique works** with the same **TAG**. And then for example you can cancel **5 unique works** with only their **1 TAG**.